# Setting pointer value without it being changed afterwards

Tags: c, pointers, strtok

I'm reading a string with space as a delimiter by using the `strtok` function.

My code looks like this:

```
char * pch = strtok (text," ");
int i = 0;
while (pch != NULL)
{
  if (i == 0)
     strcpy(name, pch);
  else
     others[i - 1] = pch;
  pch = strtok (NULL, " ");
}
```

The string looks like this: `TCP 1 2 3 4`, and `name` is of `char*` type that I receive in my function.

I wish to assign `name` to be `TCP` (i.e. first piece before the first delimiter), but because the pch pointer proceeds, the `name` variable changes when `pch` changes. How can I assign the `pch` pointer value to `name` without it being changed when the pointer changes?

Comment: Once you assign, the pointer value is copied, and the stored copy doesn't change anymore. (By the way, you forgot to increment `i`.)

Comment: What is `others[]`? Please show that as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never increment `i` so every loop ends up copying the latest value of `pch` into `name`.

You could fix it by incrementing `i` for each iteration of the loop:

```
char * pch = strtok (text," ");
int i = 0;
while (pch != NULL)
{
  if (i++ == 0) // ++ is the only change from your code
     strcpy(name, pch);
  else
     others[i - 1] = pch;
  pch = strtok (NULL, " ");
}
```

Comment: Wow, what a rookie mistake. This solved my problem! Thanks (will accept the answer in a few minutes).

Answer (score 3):

You forgot i++. You never increment i.

Answer (score 2):

Your description doesn't match your code.

Your code clearly copies *the data* (the characters) with `strcpy()`, not just the pointer. The latter would look like:

```
if (i == 0)
  name = pch;
```

but that would still work, since you've copied the pointer to the first token, and the copy won't change.

The `others` array, on the other hand, is risky if the contents of `text` changes after the loop, since there you're only storing pointers.

*EDIT*: D'oh, as others point our you're failing to increment `i`, which might explain the strangeness. Not sure why I missed this, I guess I was too confused about the disconnect between the description and the code.